# Refesh data in InMemory Mode In SSAS

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services

I have created a tabular project in "In Memory" Mode. I want to refresh the data on daily basis. Is there any way to schedule a job which will refresh the data on daily basis?

Answer (score 1):

Your options are rather limited atm

- You can't automate it directly from portal (you can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/556165-azure-analysis-services/suggestions/17026930-automated-processing-of-ssas-tabular-model-through) for such functionality)
- You can trigger refresh from azure function

  ```
  #r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\yourfunccatalog\bin\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DLL"
  #r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\yourfunccatalog\bin\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.DLL"
  #r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\yourfunccatalog\bin\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DLL"
  using System;


  public static void Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
  {
  var server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();
  server.Connect("Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://[...];User ID=[...];Password=[...];Catalog=[...];Persist Security Info=True; Impersonation Level=Impersonate;");
  var model = server.Databases[0].Model;
  model.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
  model.SaveChanges();
  server.Disconnect();
  }
  ```

You will have to upload dlls before you run it (In my case c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies)

- Azure automation might be an option if powershell is your thing. use [invoke-ASCmd servlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479579.aspx)

xmla script should look like this (haven't tested it!)

```
<Statement xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "Your database name here"
      }
    ]
  }
}

</Statement>
```

- use c# tabular object model